# deployd Error: Cannot find module 'deployd/lib/resource'

Tags: shell, terminal, deployd

i installed the file-upload module in deployd and cannot more start the deployd server.

To install, i used those commands:

```
npm install dpd-fileupload --save
cd dpd-fileupload
npm link
```

and when i start the server, i get this error

```
Error loading module node_modules/dpd-fileupload
Error: Cannot find module 'deployd/lib/resource'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/project/node_modules/dpd-fileupload/index.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at /Users/me/deployd/lib/type-loader.js:26:32
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:387:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created a link to deployd and it works.

The command:

```
npm link deployd
```

;-)

Comment: dpd-fileupload maintainer here. I updated the documentation and I'll had a peerDependencies for deployd in package.json, that will help to solve the issue.